# Motor not working when using Nano 33 BLE and transistor because of low voltage

Tags: motor, transistor, arduino-nano-ble

I'm a beginner using a new Arduino Nano 33 BLE to power a low voltage motor. I've tested that the motor can run using a standard 1.5V AA battery when connected directly, but I cannot get it to work when using the Nano to complete the circuit using a BC547 transistor.

I've attached a photo of my circuit that's as clear as I could get.
[image: My circuit]

The 1.5V motor is attached on the orange wires, I couldn't fit it in the photo.

The code I've uploaded to the Nano is as follows:

```
int power = 1023;
int outPin = D10;

void setup() {

  pinMode(outPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(outPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(outPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

When I complete the circuit with the AA battery, I can see the red LED, that's in series with the battery to the collector of the transistor, does light up but very dimly and so therefore the motor does not run either. I've also tried 2xAA and 4xAA batteries and that lights up the LED very brightly, but the motor still does not run. What could be wrong with this circuit?

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a transistor AND a LED in the circuit for the motor? The LED and the transistor will both get some of the voltage. I think the LED will dominate this. Please try without the LED

Comment: You have no series resistance for your LED.  This *may* not be a problem with a single AA battery, but it is a problem when you "also tried 2xAA and 4xAA".

Comment: I tried removing the LED and completing the circuit again but still no luck with a single AA.